# How to access Bean Id from Bean definition

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean defined in xml :

```
<bean id="Testing" class="com.test.test"/>
```

I am accessing it using the `getBean()` Is there any way to access the `id` of this bean(Testing) in my code?

Answer (score 2):

- You can get all the bean id's by using **getBeanDefinitionNames()**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

String[] beanDefinitionNames = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();

for (String bean : beanDefinitionNames) {
       System.out.println(bean);
}
```